# how to format data to box-plot

Tags: r, plot, formatting, boxplot

I am trying to boxplot this dataset and it is the only one of many who are very similar, which does not boxplot. I set my data `a <- as.numeric`. The error message I then get is: `Error in x[!xna] : object of type 'builtin' is not subsettable In addition: Warning messages: 1: In is.na(x) : is.na() applied to non-(list or vector) of type 'builtin' 2: In is.na(x) : is.na() applied to non-(list or vector) of type 'builtin'`.

The data looks like this when I type in

```
summary(a) 
#> Frontal        L45         R45        L22.5   
#> 40.0   : 2   0.0    :4   0.0    :9   na     : 4  
#> 90.0   : 2   15.0   :3   na     :3   0.0    : 2  
#> 0.0    : 1   na     :3   11.5   :1   13.2   : 1  
#> 10.0   : 1   1.7    :1   13.4   :1   14.5   : 1  
#> 10.2   : 1   15.9   :1   15.0   :1   15.0   : 1  
#> 15.0   : 1   16.5   :1   17.3   :1   15.3   : 1  
#> (Other):12   (Other):7   (Other):4   (Other):10  
#>
#> R22.5   
#> 0.0    : 4  
#> 90.0   : 2  
#> 11.7   : 1  
#> 15.0   : 1  
#> 16.0   : 1  
#> 18.9   : 1  
#> (Other):10
```

and like this in tabulated version

```
Frontal
15
58.2
3.8
9.2
23.9
0
na
22.1
46.6
5.3
40
10
32
32.5
90
89.2
72.6
40
10.2
90

L45
17
15
8.7
1.7
5
3
na
3.3
16.5
15.9
0
0
na
15
15
3.1
7.4
0
na
0

R45
11.5
23.7
0
0
0
0
na
0
0
25.5
0
0
0
2.4
15
13.4
17.3
na
5.2
na

L22.5
19.9
15.3
0
45.1
0
20.8
na
14.5
24.4
15
na
74.4
29.3
6.8
8.8
na
13.2
na
40
19.5

R22.5
40
90
57.1
11.7
2.9
0
0
na
0
36.9
80.2
15
0
90
30.3
47.7
57.6
18.9
16
24.3
```

Any troubleshooting would be greatly appreciated.
Best, 
Leah

Comment: Your data is very confusing. Perhaps you should provide a cleaner version? Is the Frontal, L45, R45 etc column headers?

Comment: Please read [How to make a great reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: I was trying to accept the data edit suggested by blazej, but I could not. How can I do that? The system told me I need 2k reputation to review edits. Can anybody implement the blazej edits, so that the data can be viewed in a clearer way?

Comment: yes, @Haakonkas, the Frontal, L45, R45 etc are the column headers.

Comment: Any help would be greatly appreciated. The issue is not resolved yet. Thanks!!!!

Comment: @Leah1, you should use `dput()` to share the data with us. If you don't know about it type `?dput()` in your terminal and read the help page.  It's generally good to demonstrate you already put some effort into it. I will also recommend `str()` when you have questions regarding the structure of your data. Regardless of the answer below, we still don't know the structure of your actual data.

Comment: Hi @Eric Fail, Thanks. I think now the data should be clear. It is five categories Frontal / L45 / R45 / L 22.5 / R 22.5, which are above listed vertically. In the .txt file that I read into R, these categories are listed one next to the other. Does that make it clear? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Did you try the `str()` function on your data? That is, `str(a)`. Please do that and compare the result to what is in my answer below.

Comment: @Eric Fail. Thanks for your elaborate answer below. The problem is, I have been able to plot other tables just like this one, but this is the only one that has some issues. So I know at the base how to do it, but in this particular table there is something that R does not like. Is it possible to send you the .txt data table via attachement in a message? I am a complete newbie here and have not fully found my way around how everything functions on this platform. Thanks!

Comment: when I put dput(a), I get the message: 
.Primitive("as.double")

Comment: when I put > a<-as.numeric and 
> str(a) I only get the output as follows:
function (x, ...)

Answer (score 2):

to help you ask better questions in the future. Please promise us to read [the article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) linked by jogo above. It's more likely that we will be able to help you if you provide [a complete minimal reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to go along with your question. Something we can work from and use to show you how it might be possible to answer your question.

Here is some data I've produced, but it is most likely not identical to your situation, as I had to guess in regard to its structure,

```
a = data.frame(Frontal = c(4L, 13L, 7L, 16L, 6L, 1L, 18L, 5L, 11L, 12L, 10L, 2L, 8L, 
                9L, 17L, 15L, 14L, 10L, 3L, 17L), L45 = c(6L, 3L, 12L, 2L, 10L, 7L, 13L, 
                9L, 5L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 13L, 3L, 3L, 8L, 11L, 1L, 13L, 1L), R45 = c(2L, 7L, 
                1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 10L, 1L, 1L, 8L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 6L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 10L, 9L, 
                10L), L22.5 = c(7L, 5L, 1L, 12L, 1L, 8L, 16L, 3L, 9L, 4L, 16L, 14L, 10L, 
                13L, 15L, 16L, 2L, 16L, 11L, 6L), R22.5 = c(10L, 15L, 12L, 2L, 6L, 1L, 1L, 
                16L, 1L, 9L, 14L, 3L, 1L, 15L, 8L, 11L, 13L, 5L, 4L, 7L))

# install.packages(c("tidyverse"), dependencies = TRUE)
library(tidyverse)
```

I suspect your data is stored as factors, despite your `as.numeric()` call. Take a look at this output of `summary()` with data `as.factor`,

```
a %>% mutate_all(as.factor) %>% summary() 
#>     Frontal        L45         R45        L22.5        R22.5   
#>  10     : 2   1      :4   1      :9   16     : 4   1      : 4  
#>  17     : 2   3      :3   10     :3   1      : 2   15     : 2  
#>  1      : 1   13     :3   2      :1   2      : 1   2      : 1  
#>  2      : 1   2      :1   3      :1   3      : 1   3      : 1  
#>  3      : 1   4      :1   4      :1   4      : 1   4      : 1  
#>  4      : 1   5      :1   5      :1   5      : 1   5      : 1  
#>  (Other):12   (Other):7   (Other):4   (Other):10   (Other):10
```

you can compare that to how it looks when using `summary()` on my data (that I know is numeric),

```
a %>%  summary() 
#>     Frontal           L45             R45            L22.5           R22.5      
#>  Min.   : 1.00   Min.   : 1.00   Min.   : 1.00   Min.   : 1.00   Min.   : 1.00  
#>  1st Qu.: 5.75   1st Qu.: 2.75   1st Qu.: 1.00   1st Qu.: 4.75   1st Qu.: 2.75  
#>  Median :10.00   Median : 5.50   Median : 2.50   Median : 9.50   Median : 7.50  
#>  Mean   : 9.90   Mean   : 6.30   Mean   : 4.15   Mean   : 9.25   Mean   : 7.70  
#>  3rd Qu.:14.25   3rd Qu.:10.25   3rd Qu.: 7.25   3rd Qu.:14.25   3rd Qu.:12.25  
#>  Max.   :18.00   Max.   :13.00   Max.   :10.00   Max.   :16.00   Max.   :16.00
```

if you want to give people a glimpse of your data, you can do something like this,

```
a %>% as_tibble() %>% print(n = 7)
#> # A tibble: 20 x 5
#>   Frontal   L45   R45 L22.5 R22.5
#>     <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
#> 1       4     6     2     7    10
#> 2      13     3     7     5    15
#> 3       7    12     1     1    12
#> 4      16     2     1    12     2
#> 5       6    10     1     1     6
#> 6       1     7     1     8     1
#> 7      18    13    10    16     1
#> # ... with 13 more rows
```

the above output also show how the individual vectors in `a` are stored. Here they are all stored as integers, `int`. You can also use the actual `glimpse()` from the [tidyverse](/questions/tagged/tidyverse) packages,

```
a %>% as_tibble() %>% glimpse()
#> Observations: 20
#> Variables: 5
#> $ Frontal <int> 4, 13, 7, 16, 6, 1, 18, 5, 11, 12, ... 
#> $ L45     <int> 6, 3, 12, 2, 10, 7, 13, 9, 5, 4, 1, ...
#> $ R45     <int> 2, 7, 1, 1, 1, 1, 10, 1, 1, 8, 1, 1...
#> $ L22.5   <int> 7, 5, 1, 12, 1, 8, 16, 3, 9, 4, 16, ...
#> $ R22.5   <int> 10, 15, 12, 2, 6, 1, 1, 16, 1, 9, ...
```

maybe `str()` from [base-r](/questions/tagged/base-r) is actually better here,

```
str(a)
#> 'data.frame':    20 obs. of  5 variables:
#>  $ Frontal: int  4 13 7 16 6 1 18 5 11 12 ...
#>  $ L45    : int  6 3 12 2 10 7 13 9 5 4 ...
#>  $ R45    : int  2 7 1 1 1 1 10 1 1 8 ...
#>  $ L22.5  : int  7 5 1 12 1 8 16 3 9 4 ...
#>  $ R22.5  : int  10 15 12 2 6 1 1 16 1 9 ...
```

All three output options show that the vectors in the data (I produced) are integers, `int`, i.e. they are numeric. You should investigate your datas structure and make sure its numeric. If not you can use `a %>% mutate_all(as.numeric)` to get there.

Enough of that. Here's one box-plot option on `a`, though I do not know if this is what you are looking for,

```
a %>% gather()  %>% ggplot(aes(key, value))  + geom_boxplot()
```

[image: sigh-sight]

wanted to elaborate the `gather()` call a bit to show how it works,

```
a %>% gather(key = "Type: L, R, or Frontal", value = "int value") %>% 
        ggplot(aes(`Type: L, R, or Frontal`, `int value`)) + 
        geom_boxplot(fill = "white", colour = "#3366FF") + 
        geom_jitter(width = .2, colour = "#3366FF", alpha = 0.4)
```

[image: get a life]